# how to get the unique occurences from a file in linux

Tags: linux, shell, grep, uniq

i have a data.txt file as below

```
1
1
100
100
1
1
1
```

when i tried,

```
more 'data.txt|uniq'
```

I get the uniq value of multiple occurrences consecutively

```
1
100
1
```

Is there a way, i can get the result as

```
1
100
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try executing

$ sort -u data.txt

Description:

according to manpage of uniq

> Note: 'uniq' does not detect repeated lines unless they are adjacent. 
>   You may want to sort the input first, or use 'sort -u' without 'uniq'.

you can read manpage by executing

$ man uniq